# Disable body scroll while scrolling iframe in MOBILE

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, document-body

Below code

In computer, I can disable body scroll while scrolling iframe by detecting mouse

In mobile, I am trying to disable body scroll by detecting touch in body but NOT WORK. I can see h1 changed to auto if I touch a point outside of `simulator` and h1 not changed to auto if I touch `simulator`.

Any suggestion to fix it?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

        <section>

            <iframe id="simulator" style="background: #000000;" src="" width="378px" height="1500px" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

            <h1 id="toucheventtt">dsds</p>

            <script>
                function disable_scroll() {
                    document.body.style.overflow="hidden";
                    document.getElementById("toucheventtt").innerHTML = "hidden";
                }
                function enable_scroll() {
                    document.body.style.overflow="auto";
                    document.getElementById("toucheventtt").innerHTML = "auto";
                }
                document.getElementById("simulator").onmouseenter = disable_scroll;
                document.getElementById("simulator").onmouseleave = enable_scroll;

                document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
                    enable_scroll();
                }, false)
                document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function(){
                    disable_scroll();
                }, false)
            </script>

        </section>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also adding below code only work for computer.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <style>
        html, body {
            overflow-y: hidden;
        }
        body {
            position: relative;
        }
    </style>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to use these properties:

for onmouseenter you can use touchstart that Triggers when the user makes contact with the touch surface and creates a touch point inside the element the event is bound to.

> touchstart

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchstart', function(){
    document.body.style.overflow="hidden";
}, false)
```

for onmouseleave you can use touchend that triggers when the user removes a touch point from the surface. It fires regardless of whether the touch point is removed while inside the bound-to element, or outside, such as if the user's finger slides out of the element first or even off the edge of the screen.

> touchend

```
document.body.addEventListener('touchend', function(){
    document.body.style.overflow="auto";
}, false)
```

Comment: mmmm try to add the listener on the simulator element like so: `document.getElementById("simulator").addEventListener('touchend', function()...`

Comment: btw, if touchstart in body, it should be ```overflow="auto"``` to enable scroll?

Comment: yeah it should be

Comment: see my edited post. the code is exactly what I am testing